# OpenAI gym keyboard_agent.py: How to restart?

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I want to use the [`keyboard_agent.py`](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/examples/agents/keyboard_agent.py) to play `Breakout-v0`. 
When I start the environment with:

```
python [...]/gym/examples/agents/keyboard_agent.py "Breakout-v0"
```

The game starts, and I can play the first round no problem. I can't however make it restart!

In the code we have:

```
 if key==0xff0d: human_wants_restart = True
```

Which I can't get to work. [Google tells me](https://www.google.co.kr/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=0xff0d&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=_lxCWYHNNIeDqAHS15OwDg) that `0xff0d` is `FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS`. What am I doing wrong, or how do I make this character?

Answer (score 0):

Restart is `enter`, and pause is `space`.